# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.testing.models.Account

Tags: java, jackson, rest-assured

I'm getting below error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.testing.models.Account
```

with below code

```
final int expectedId = 1;

Test newTest = create();

int expectedResponseCode = Response.SC_OK;

ArrayList<Account> account = given().when().expect().statusCode(expectedResponseCode)
    .get("accounts/" + newTest.id() + "/users")
    .as(ArrayList.class);
assertThat(account.get(0).getId()).isEqualTo(expectedId);
```

Is there a reason why I cannot do `get(0)`?

Comment: Cannot be cast to **what**?  What is the rest of the error message?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth also added entire stacktrace

Comment: What's an `Account`? Why are you trying to cast to it from a map?

Comment: For those of us who might be unfamiliar with the library, can you say what class this `given()` method is statically imported from?

Comment: @DaveNewton `Account` is a model from Dropwizard which uses `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotations`

Comment: Where do you use LinkedHashMap in your code?

Comment: @MarkPeters it's `com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.given`

Comment: To library link is https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured

Comment: Seems to me you are trying to deserialize JSON string onto Java object. The problem might be in structure mismatch. You should put here response from this URL:"accounts/" + newClub.getOwner().getCustId() + "/clubs" and Account class

Answer (score 155, accepted):

The issue's coming from Jackson. When it doesn't have enough information on what class to deserialize to, it uses `LinkedHashMap`.

Since you're not informing Jackson of the element type of your `ArrayList`, it doesn't know that you want to deserialize into an `ArrayList` of `Account`s.  So it falls back to the default.

Instead, you could probably use `as(JsonNode.class)`, and then deal with the `ObjectMapper` in a richer manner than rest-assured allows.  Something like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

JsonNode accounts = given().when().expect().statusCode(expectedResponseCode)
    .get("accounts/" + newClub.getOwner().getCustId() + "/clubs")
    .as(JsonNode.class);


//Jackson's use of generics here are completely unsafe, but that's another issue
List<Account> accountList = mapper.convertValue(
    accounts, 
    new TypeReference<List<Account>>(){}
);

assertThat(accountList.get(0).getId()).isEqualTo(expectedId);
```

Comment: You can also set the response asString(), saves having to do extra conversions - readValue will accept a String as the first arg.

Comment: @BIGDeutsch: Just revisiting this, there was no need for me to convert back to tokens there when `convertValue` could do it in one step.  Going to a string works too.

Comment: what to do when an object contains a varibale which is  list . How to deserialize the object using jackson ?

Answer (score 71):

Try the following:

```
POJO pojo = mapper.convertValue(singleObject, POJO.class);
```

or:

```
List<POJO> pojos = mapper.convertValue(
    listOfObjects,
    new TypeReference<List<POJO>>() { });
```

See [conversion of LinkedHashMap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430715/casting-linkedhashmap-to-complex-object) for more information.

Comment: +1 for showing "convertValue".  I had a case where I needed to read a particular property out of json as a List and this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 45):

The way I could mitigate the **JSON Array to collection of LinkedHashMap objects** problem was by using `CollectionType` rather than a  `TypeReference` .
This is what I did and **worked**:

```
public <T> List<T> jsonArrayToObjectList(String json, Class<T> tClass) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    CollectionType listType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, tClass);
    List<T> ts = mapper.readValue(json, listType);
    LOGGER.debug("class name: {}", ts.get(0).getClass().getName());
    return ts;
}
```

---

Using the `TypeReference`, I was still getting an ArrayList of LinkedHashMaps, i.e. **does not work**:

```
public <T> List<T> jsonArrayToObjectList(String json, Class<T> tClass) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List<T> ts = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<T>>(){});
    LOGGER.debug("class name: {}", ts.get(0).getClass().getName());
    return ts;
}
```

Comment: +1, the difference in your case was that the method itself was generic so `T` could not be reified via the TypeToken, which is typically easier.  Personally I prefer Guava's helper because it's still typesafe and not specific to any container type: `return new TypeToken<List<T>>(){}.where(new TypeParameter<T>(){}, tClass)`.  But Jackson doesn't take `TypeToken`s so you then need `.getType()`.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar exception (but different problem) -  `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to org.bson.Document` , and fortunately it's solved easier:

Instead of

```
List<Document> docs = obj.get("documents");
Document doc = docs.get(0)
```

which gives error on second line, One can use

```
List<Document> docs = obj.get("documents");
Document doc = new Document(docs.get(0));
```

Comment: How did you set up your constructor for the Document class?

Answer (score 1):

Solve problem with two method parse common

1. Whith type is an object

```
public <T> T jsonToObject(String json, Class<T> type) {
        T target = null;
        try {
            target = objectMapper.readValue(json, type);
        } catch (Jsenter code hereonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
        return target;
    }
```

2. With type is collection wrap object

```
public <T> T jsonToObject(String json, TypeReference<T> type) {
    T target = null;
    try {
        target = objectMapper.readValue(json, type);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return target;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is something i used in my project, Json object was returned, i converted it to a List of POJO, List and then accessed the element.
I took the input of Json object from another microservice.

Main thing is:-
**JsonNode stocks = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:2000/stocks/qty", JsonNode.class);
List<Stock_id_qty> stockList = mapper.convertValue(stocks, new TypeReference<List<Stock_id_qty>>() {});**

```
@GetMapping("/")
    public List<Stock_id_qty> checkQty() throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode stocks = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:2000/stocks/qty", JsonNode.class);
        List<Stock_id_qty> stockList = mapper.convertValue(stocks, new TypeReference<List<Stock_id_qty>>() {});
        List<Stock_id_qty> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Stock_id_qty s : stockList){
            if(s.getStockQty() < 10)
            {
                result.add(s);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this method for deserializing an XML and converting the type:

```
public <T> Object deserialize(String xml, Class objClass ,TypeReference<T> typeReference ) throws IOException {
    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    Object obj = xmlMapper.readValue(xml,objClass);
    return  xmlMapper.convertValue(obj,typeReference );   
}
```

and this is the call:

```
List<POJO> pojos = (List<POJO>) MyUtilClass.deserialize(xml, ArrayList.class,new TypeReference< List< POJO >>(){ });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use jackson to map from string to your concrete class, especially if you work with generic type. then this issue may happen because of different class loader. i met it one time with below scenarior:

Project B depend on Library A

in Library A:

```
public class DocSearchResponse<T> {
 private T data;
}
```

it has service to query data from external source, and use jackson to convert to concrete class

```
public class ServiceA<T>{
  @Autowired
  private ObjectMapper mapper;
  @Autowired
  private ClientDocSearch searchClient;

  public DocSearchResponse<T> query(Criteria criteria){
      String resultInString = searchClient.search(criteria);
      return convertJson(resultInString)
  }
}

public DocSearchResponse<T> convertJson(String result){
     return mapper.readValue(result, new TypeReference<DocSearchResponse<T>>() {});
  }
}
```

in Project B:

```
public class Account{
 private String name;
 //come with other attributes
}
```

and i use ServiceA from library to make query and as well convert data

```
public class ServiceAImpl extends ServiceA<Account> {
    
}
```

and make use of that

```
public class MakingAccountService {
    @Autowired
    private ServiceA service;
    public void execute(Criteria criteria){
      
        DocSearchResponse<Account> result = service.query(criteria);
        Account acc = result.getData(); //  java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.testing.models.Account
    }
}
```

it happen because from classloader of LibraryA, jackson can not load Account class, then just override method `convertJson` in Project B to let jackson do its job

```
public class ServiceAImpl extends ServiceA<Account> {
        @Override
        public DocSearchResponse<T> convertJson(String result){
         return mapper.readValue(result, new TypeReference<DocSearchResponse<T>>() {});
      }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> public class ObjectHelper {
>
>   private static ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
>
>   public static ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
>     objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL).configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES,false);
>     return objectMapper;
>   } 
> }
> ```

Use

> ```
> FetchResponse fetchResponse =
> ObjectHelper.getObjectMapper().convertValue(
>                     data, new TypeReference<FetchResponse>() {});
> ```

OR

```
List<Map<String, Object>> responseObj = (List<Map<String, Object>>) response.get("content");

List<LkAuthUserDetail> responseData = ObjectHelper.getObjectMapper().convertValue(responseObj,
                    new TypeReference<List<LkAuthUserDetail>>() {});
```

Answer (score 0):

We faced a similar sort of issue in our microservices communication. We had two services `approval` and `transfer`, so once a transfer is approved there will be a communication between the above services using `Kafka`, where the `transfer` will be the consumer.

Both the services are maintaining a common bean `Payload`, which has some fields as `Object` type

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Payload extends KafkaParameters implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Object requestedBy;
    private Object requestDetails;
    private Object payload;
    private Object existingPayload;
    private Object payloadDifference;
}
```

Initially from the `transfer` service we'll set the value to the `payload` attribute inside `Payload` bean which will be a reference of type `TransactionRequest`. So, once the consumer in the `transfer` service is getting the callback from the `approval` service we are getting the `Payload` and when we tried to downcast we got this error

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class AdjustmentApprovalConsumer {

    @KafkaListener(topics = TransferConstants.ADJUSTMENT_APPROVAL_TOPIC, containerFactory = "ApprovalConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void listenCdr(@org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Payload Payload approvalRequest) {

        TransactionRequest request = (TransactionRequest) approvalRequest.getPayload();
    }
}
```

We fixed this issues by using two methods

1. Convert the payload to a JSON string

```
    public static String asJsonString(final Object obj) {
        try {
            return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(obj);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

2. Convert the JSON string to a given bean

```
    public static <T> Object jsonToObject(final String json, Class<T> type) {
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            return mapper.readValue(json, type);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

So the final code was like this

```
TransactionRequest request = (TransactionRequest) JsonUtils.jsonToObject(JsonUtils.asJsonString(approvalRequest.getPayload()), TransactionRequest.class);
```

This is may not be a conventional way of doing it but surely fixed the issue.