# Returning and Casting ResponseEntity<List<T>>

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-rest

I'm trying to return a `ResponseEntity` list and casting that response respect to my model classes.

For instance: if I use `ResponseEntity<List<ApplicationModel>>` it's working well but I do not want to write a response method per model.

**`ResponseEntity` method**

```
    public static <T> ResponseEntity<List<T>> getResponseList(String resourceURL) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

    HttpEntity<List<T>> entity = new HttpEntity<List<T>>(headers);
    ResponseEntity<List<T>> response = restTemplate.exchange(resourceURL, HttpMethod.GET, entity,
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<T>>() {
            }, Collections.emptyMap());

    return response;
}
```

**Method call**

```
    private final String url ="http://localhost:8090/xxx/application";

    ResponseEntity<List<ApplicationModel> responseForApplications =
 ResponseTemplate.getResponseList(url);

    if (responseForApplications.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) 
         List<ApplicationModel> dtoApplications = responseForApplications.getBody();
```

**Example of JSON response which I want to cast**

> {"id":1,"name":"foo","description":"foo"}

**Error**

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
>   Error creating bean with name 'index': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.xxx.ApplicationModel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The issue's coming from Jackson. When it doesn't have enough
>   information on what class to deserialize to, it uses LinkedHashMap.
>
> Since you're not informing Jackson of the element type of your
>   ArrayList, it doesn't know that you want to deserialize into an
>   ArrayList of *ApplicationModels*. So it falls back to the default.
>
> Instead, you could probably use as(JsonNode.class), and then deal with
>   the ObjectMapper in a richer manner than rest-assured allows.

Please refer to [java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.testing.models.Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28821715/java-lang-classcastexception-java-util-linkedhashmap-cannot-be-cast-to-com-test) for additional information.

Answer (score 2):

Using `mapper.convertValue` works for me.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<ApplicationModel> dtoApplications = mapper.convertValue(responseForApproles.getBody(), new TypeReference<List<ApplicationModel>>() {});
```