# Convert LinkedHashMap into custom java object android

Tags: java, android, jackson, jackson2

I'm using `jackson` to read and write object into local json file.
It successfully read and write value. But problem is when I read value from file. and assign it to my object it give me an error.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.testing.FeedItem

I know the reason of error because to read value from file jackons use `LinkedHashMap` So, `LinkedHashMap` can not cast to object(FeedItem)

Here is what I'm using.

**PostFeed**

```
  public class PostFeed{
       private String name;
       private List<FeedItem> feeditemList;
       // other code getter setter etc
  }
```

**Reading Value from File**

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
PostFeed postFeed = objectMapper.readValue(offlinePrivateFeed, PostFeed.class);

FeedItem feedItem = postFeed.getFeedList().get(0); // Error
```

**Update Write Value to local File**

```
     ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
     objectMapper.writeValue(Utils.getOutputJsonFile("private-feed"), postFeed);
```

I found similar question [LinkedhashMap can not cast to model Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28821715/java-lang-classcastexception-java-util-linkedhashmap-cannot-be-cast-to-com-test) But this question is not useful in my case, Almost I tried all answer but no one solve my problem.

Can you please let me know how can I solve this ?

**Update: FeedItem**

```
  public class FeedItem{
     private String name;
     private int badge;
     private Boolean allow;
     // other code getter setter etc
  }
```

**Update: JSON File**

```
{
 "feedName": "test123",
 "time" : "7-7-1994",
 "feedList": [
  {
   "name": "feedItemName",
   "badge": 4,
   "allow": false
  },
  {
   "name": "feedItemName",
   "badge": 1,
   "allow": true
  },
  {
   "name": "feedItemName",
   "badge": 2,
   "allow": false
  }

  ]

}
```

**Update: Solution**

This problem can be slove by converting `LinkedHashMap` into custom object `FeedItem` But question is how we can convert `LinkedHashMap` into `Object` ?

Comment: so, you know the reason of the error ... what more do you want us to explain to you?

Comment: I want how can I assign `LinkedHashMap` to my object (FeedItem) ?

Comment: ehm ... not. you might want to map the contents of your LinkedHashMap

Comment: can you show what your local file looks like?

Comment: @Stultuske I only want to convert `LinkedHashMap` into object `FeedItem`

Comment: did you solve the problem @AzeemHaider

Answer (score 0):

LinkedHashMap implements Map not List

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html

Maybe change your feeditemList field type to LinkedHashMap

Comment: I can not change it because I'm using Google Cloud Endpoint library and `FeedItem` is auto generated file

Answer (score 0):

Try this code if your PostFeed object not null then also feeditemList is not empty then used below code..

```
    if (postFeed!=null &&  !postFeed.getFeedList().isEmpty()){

        FeedItem feedItem = postFeed.getFeedList().get(0);
    }
```

Comment: Bro, if you read my question It's not a `NullPointerExcdption` it's `ClassCastException`

Comment: sorry for that i think error into PostFeed postFeed = objectMapper.readValue(offlinePrivateFeed, PostFeed.class);
this line not  this  line 
        FeedItem feedItem = postFeed.getFeedList().get(0);

Comment: you can debug and check it.

Comment: I know where the error and what the error is Because problem is I don't know how to solve this

Comment: From local file, I updated my question see how I'm writing value in local file

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
`  public class PostFeed{
       private String name;
       private LinkedHashMap<FeedItem> feeditemList;
//     private Map<FreedItem> freeditemlist
       // or you can also do this
       // other code getter setter etc
  }`
```

because LinkedHashMap implements Map not List

Comment: As I already comment I can not change this file Because it is auto generated file from Google cloud storage

Comment: ok so you have to convert the retrieved data into FeedItem  object

Comment: first try to know what you are getting in postFeed.getFeedList().get(0); by getting it into object type field than you can cast accordingly

Comment: I'm getting `LinkedHashMap` from `postFeed.getFeedList().get(0)` Cast this to `FeedItem` does not work same error

Comment: And In your code `LinkedHashMap` require two paramters `key` and `value` value type differ for each item. check update