# Filter a list of POJO using streams - getting ClassCastException java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast

Tags: java, serialization, java-8, stream, jackson

As familiar as the question is, my problem is a little odd.

This is the POJO I have:

```
public class POJO implements Serializable {
    @JsonProperty("ID")
    private UUID id;

    @JsonProperty("Name")
    private String name;

    // getters and setters
}
```

I am trying to filter a list of this POJO using the following piece of code:

```
List<POJO> pojoList = getListOfPojosFromSomeMethod();
List<POJO> filteredPOJO = pojoList.stream()
                          .filter(p -> p.getName().equals("POJOName"))
                          .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

I am unable to filter the list. I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.models.POJO
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:174)
at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining (ArrayList.java:1374)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at 
java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at 
java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
```

I tried to use map as well:

```
List<POJO> pojoList = getListOfPojosFromSomeMethod();
List<POJO> filteredPOJO = pojoList.stream()
                          .filter(p -> p.getName().equals("POJOName")
                          .map(p -> new POJO(p))
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Same exception. No change whatsoever. I read somewhere that the exception is because of Jackson serialization.

How do I filter lists using streams and Jackson at the same time? I am unable to find a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possibly a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28821715/java-lang-classcastexception-java-util-linkedhashmap-cannot-be-cast-to-com-test?rq=1 ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with streams or collect, etc. The problem is known as [**heap pollution**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/nonReifiableVarargsType.html#heap_pollution) and is about tricking the compiler so that it thinks that your `pojoList` is a `List<POJO>` when it's actually a `List<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>` (which is the type used by JSON serialization/deserialization libraries when there's not enough information about types available). Hint: If you're using strange casts inside the `getListOfPojosFromSomeMethod` method, I bet this is the problem.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I was retrieving the List<Pojo> from a Hashmap inside the `getListOfPojosFromSomeMethod` method. Once I used proper casting while retrieving them, the streams worked seamlessly!

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
Predicate<POJO> filterPredicate = item -> "POJOName".equals(item.getName());

List<POJO> filteredPOJOs = pojoList.stream()
                      .filter(filterPredicate)
                      .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: If it doesn't work you can try creating the stream using **StreamSupport**
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in the first example :

```
    List<POJO> filteredPOJO = pojoList.stream()
                      .filter(p -> p.getName().equals("POJOName"))
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I just noticed that a parenthesis is missing after : equals("POJOName") to close filter params.